# defaultAppConfig is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

So when I paste in the Firebase setup code for Node.js, I'm getting this error:

> defaultAppConfig is not defined

Here is the full block of code:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);
var defaultStorage = defaultApp.storage();
var defaultDatabase = defaultApp.database();
```

Comment: Copied from where exactly?  The error message is telling you that you never defined `defaultAppConfig`, which is totally true in the code you're showing.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a variable **defaultAppConfig** which is not defined.

Define defaultAppConfig or pass nothing to the initializeApp method.

```
var defaultAppConfig = {};
var defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);
```

or

```
var defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp();
```

Comment: When I do that, I now get this error: `var defaultStorage = defaultApp.storage();
                                ^

TypeError: defaultApp.storage is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

In your case `defaultAppConfig` is a variable...and you don't initialize it ;)
I think you should go to the doc on [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk)